# Missing files in visual studio 2008 project

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

I am new to Visual Studio and forgive me if my question is trivial.

My collegue gave me recently a copy of his Visual Studio project. On my computer, however, I cannot compile it.

The problem is that I do not have access to the files (source and header files) that are visible in the project explorer. The problem is that the path of theses files is still the same path that my collegue was using.

How can I fix this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the .vcproj file with a text editor, Notepad is fine.  The path of source files is *normally* a relative path.  They won't be if he had his source files stored on another drive.

Comment: Ok, there are my problems. Thank you!